# Reach activity from DialogPreference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have a DialogPreference that I open from a PreferenceActivity.
I would like to close the PreferenceActivity when the DialogPreference is closed.
In the class SeekBarPreference extends DialogPreference, I have

```
@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {


}
```

Here I need a reference to the SettingsActivity so I can finish() it.

In comparaison, when I manage a DialogFragment, I can use the Callback Method :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    parentActivity = ((MapActivity) activity);
}
```

How can I do to close my settingsActivity from DialogPreference???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While creating the dialog preference, you are taking in the context right?

Then cast the context to Activity and call finish.

```
//Field Variable
private Context mContext;

//Your Constructor
public  DialogPreference(Context context){
    mContext=context
}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    ((Activity)mContext).finish();
}
```